# Database objects are not showing on SSMS Object Explorer Azure DB

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database

I have created azure db instance Connected to my windows azure database using SSMS. My newly created database (as admin) all the tables show up within my object explorer when I login is as the SA for the sql server in question.

But..this is where I'm scratching my head.

I created another user, I can also see database and connect to db but objects (tables) within my object explorer are not there. I have tried allow user to have all roles except denys, granting connect to users and public. But no joy. also tried in VS same effect. Also have upgraded SSMS to latest version.

I have also noticed dbo shows disabled in SSMS when login as new user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was down to creating a user and roles but not a login after creating user in master.

EDIT: [For more on various types of principals.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lcris/2007/03/23/basic-sql-server-security-concepts-logins-users-and-principals/)

Comment: One neat feature with Azure SQL allows you to create contained users that don't need a corresponding login.  This helps make the database more portable:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929188.aspx